# Generating random number stops application

Tags: java, android, random

I am trying to generate a random number on clicking the `Button` and print the value in `EditText`

I made it with this code

```
public class Board_Play1 extends Activity {

int d;
Random random = new Random();
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board_play1);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d=random.nextInt(6)+1;
            EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            diceno.setText(d);

        }
    }); 

}
```

But on running application after clicking the button it pops up an error saying `Unfortunately, your app has stopped`. Cant understand why it is so. Can anyone explain what the mistake is?

Comment: d is an int, you should use `String.valueOf(d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `setText` method that accepts a `CharSequence` as argument.

Currently you're calling `setText(int resid)` which will try to find the correct resource with the id specified, so I guess your program is throwing a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

So do:

```
diceno.setText(String.valueOf(d));
```

This will convert your `int` to `String`.

Also move the `EditText diceno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` before the `onClick` method. There is no need to retrieve it on each `onClick` event, just once suffice.

Finally in future, don't forget to post the stacktrace with your question.